# RDS MySQL comparison of source RDS and restored RDS via snapshot

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have a source RDS Aurora MySQL cluster and I need to migrate the entire cluster to another account in the same region.
I will be doing this using snapshot approach.

I need to give a our acounting team a proof of the integrity of the source and destination RDS cluster that indeed all the databases inside the source RDS cluster have been restored to the destination RDS cluster.

Any ideas how can I perform this test ?

Comment: No because it's like saying "how do I have proof that my Lambdas are actually running my code" - you run them is the answer. Same thing applies here - if there are no errors during replication, you trust AWS to have copied over the data correctly just like you trust them for everything else. Ultimate proof is manually checking the resulting snapshot restore but I'd be pushing back against accounting in that case.

Comment: Any native MySQL query that can do the check integrity check or comparison of source and destination databases using either Workbench or cli ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/ but not related to AWS.